# Using the convolution theorem and FFT does not lead to the same result as the scipy.convolve function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, convolution

I want to get familiar with the fourier based convolutions. Therefore, I created a small example using `numpy.fft` and `scipy.signal.convolve`. However, the results of the two operations are different and 
I do not know why. 
Does someone has an idea?

I have already tried to use the different modes of `scipy.signal.convolve`.

The example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve

# Generate example data
data = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
kernel = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0])

# Using scipy.signal.convolve
A = convolve(kernel, data, mode='full')
B = convolve(kernel, data, mode='valid')
C = convolve(kernel, data, mode='same')

# Using the convolution theorem 
D = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft(kernel) * np.fft.fft(data))
```

---

The results are:

```py
A = array([0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0])
B = array([4])
C = array([3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3])

D = array([4.+0.j, 4.+0.j, 4.+0.j, 4.+0.j, 4.+0.j, 4.+0.j])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pad `data` and `kernel` with N-1 zeroes to avoid circular convolution...

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve

# Generate example data
data = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
kernel = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0])

# Using scipy.signal.convolve
A = convolve(kernel, data, mode='full')

# Using the convolution theorem - need to pad with N-1 zeroes
data = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
kernel = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

D = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft(kernel) * np.fft.fft(data))

print (A)
print (D)
```

[Result:](https://repl.it/repls/RegalHelplessArchitecture)

```
[0 1 3 4 4 4 4 3 1 0 0]
[2.4e-16+0.j 1.0e+00+0.j 3.0e+00+0.j 4.0e+00+0.j 4.0e+00+0.j 4.0e+00+0.j
 4.0e+00+0.j 3.0e+00+0.j 1.0e+00+0.j 3.2e-16+0.j 1.6e-16+0.j]
```

Comment: Don't pad to a prime length. It's better to overpad to a length that has no large prime factors. If you have scipy you can use `scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len` to obtain the next good length.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: good point - from an efficiency perspective the FFT length should be a product of powers of small primes ideally.

Comment: Thanks, for the example. Why do I not pad symmetrical?

Comment: Using `scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len` would not be sufficient in this example. It results in an array with length six, which still leads in inequality of both operations.

Comment: @beckstev You have to use it on the minimum required length, in the example: `scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len(len(data)+len(kernel)-1)`.